# assigning title to intervals in pandas

Tags: pandas, numpy

```
import numpy as np
xlist = np.arange(1, 100).tolist()
df = pd.DataFrame(xlist,columns=['Numbers'],dtype=int)
pd.cut(df['Numbers'],5)
```

how to assign column name to each distinct intervals created ?

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: suppose there is dataframe with number from 1 to 100 then i have to create 5 columns with interval of 20 then assign new column for each interval. For eg: Column 1 1 to 20 , column 2 : 21 to 40 etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `pd.concat` function and join them in a new data frame based on indexes:

```
# get indexes
l = df.index.tolist()
n =20
indexes = [l[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]

# create new data frame
new_df = pd.concat([df.iloc[x].reset_index(drop=True) for x in indexes], axis=1)
new_df.columns = ['Numbers'+str(x) for x in range(new_df.shape[1])]

print(new_df)

   Numbers0  Numbers1  Numbers2  Numbers3  Numbers4
0         1        21        41        61      81.0
1         2        22        42        62      82.0
2         3        23        43        63      83.0
3         4        24        44        64      84.0
4         5        25        45        65      85.0
```

Comment: are you using the exact same code given in question ?